# Problema de lógica formación de números con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Necesito que el usuario ingrese un número del 1 al 8 en función de la preferencia de la opción, donde 1 es el más importante y 8 el menos importante. Debe existir el caso que si teclea 0 es como 'No interesado' y no afecta el proceso. No puede haber números duplicados en el formulario (a excepción del 0 que es como 'No interesado'), mandar error de lo contrario. Si el input no tiene valor, poner 0 por default. Todo me surge bien, pero si pongo dos números ceros y dos números cualquiera me aparece como si fuera correcto y pasaría al AJAX.

Tengo este código HTML

```
 <table class="table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Cubrir esta guardia</th>
    <th>Fecha</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g1" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Domingo 1 de Enero</td>
    <td>Año nuevo</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g2" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Lunes 6 de Febrero</td>
    <td>Día de la constitución mexicana</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g3" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Lunes 20 de Marzo</td>
    <td>Natalicio de Benito Juárez</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g4" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Domingo 16 de Abril</td>
    <td>Domingo de resurección</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g5" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Lunes 1 de Mayo</td>
    <td>Día del trabajo</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g6" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Sábado 16 de Septiembre</td>
    <td>Día de la independencia</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g7" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Lunes 20 de Noviembre</td>
    <td>Revolución Mexicana</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="g8" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
    <td>Domingo 25 de Diciembre</td>
    <td>Navidad</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

y este es mi JS

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_guardia',function()
{
  var values_arr = [];
  $('.num').each(function() //RECORRER LOS INPUT PARA SACARLES VALOR
  {
    if ($(this).val() == "" ||$(this).val() < 0 || $(this).val() > 8) //SI SON VACIOS, MAYORES A 8 Y MENORES A 0 PONERLOS EN 0
    {
        $(this).val('0');
    }
    values_arr.push($(this).val()); //EMPUJAR EL VALOR ACTUAL AL ARREGLO
  });

  var sorted_arr = values_arr.slice().sort(); //SACAR UN ARREGLO IGUAL AL ORIGINAL PERO ACOMODADO
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values_arr.length - 1; i++)//RECORRER EL ARREGLO
  {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) //BUSCAR SI HAY VALORES REPETIDOS
    {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);//EMPUJAR AL ARREGLO RESULTADO EL VALOR DUPLICADO
    }
  }

  if (results.length > 0) //VERIFICAR SI HUBO VALORES DUPLICADOS
  {
    if (jQuery.inArray('0',results) == -1) //SI LOS HUBO PREGUNTAR SI ESTE FUE DIFERENTE DE 0
    {
        alert('Hay items duplicados');
    }

    else
    {
          alert('Llamada a AJAX, hay ceros pero no importa');
    }
  }

  else
  {
      alert('Llamada a AJAX, no hay ceros ni otros numeros');
      alert(values_arr);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kyf7w77b/

Todas las sugerencias son bienvenidas.

Comment: Por favor, no pongs un enlace al código, publica el código directamente en StackOverflow.

Comment: Ya puse el código, gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Para detectar duplicados, creamos un `diccionario` y una bandera `hayDuplicados`. Si detectamos que un número no existente en el `diccionario` lo guardamos. Si llegara a aparecer nuevamente cambiamos la bandera `hayDuplicados` a `true`.
- Para detectar ceros, creamos una bandera `hayCeros`. Si llegara a parecer un cero, un espacio, un número menor a 0 o mayor a 8, cambiamos el valor del `$input` a `cero` y cambiamos la bandera `hayCeros` a `true`.

El código podría ser el siguiente:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn_guardia', function () {
  var values_arr = [],
    hayCeros = false,
    hayDuplicados = false,
    diccionario = {};

  // RECORRER LOS INPUT PARA SACARLES VALOR
  $('.num').each(function () {
    // Obtenemos el valor 
    var $input = $(this),
      value = parseInt($input.val(), 10);

    // Si es 0, vacio, menor a cero o mayor a 8 
    if (!value || value < 0 || value > 8) {
      hayCeros = true;
      value = 0;
      $input.val(value);
    }
    // Si el valor no esta duplicado (no existe en el hash)
    else if (!diccionario[value]) {
      diccionario[value] = true;
    }
    // Si el valor esta duplicado
    else {
      hayDuplicados = true;
    }

    // EMPUJAR EL VALOR ACTUAL AL ARREGLO
    values_arr.push(value);
  });

  // Si hay duplicados
  if (hayDuplicados) {
    alert('Hay items duplicados');
  }
  // Si hay ceros
  else if (hayCeros) {
    alert('Llamada a AJAX, ceros pero no importa');
    alert(values_arr);
  }
  // Si no hay duplicados ni ceros
  else {
    alert('Llamada a AJAX, no hay ceros ni otros numeros');
    alert(values_arr);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cubrir esta guardia</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g1" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Domingo 1 de Enero</td>
        <td>Año nuevo</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g2" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Lunes 6 de Febrero</td>
        <td>Día de la constitución mexicana</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g3" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Lunes 20 de Marzo</td>
        <td>Natalicio de Benito Juárez</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g4" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Domingo 16 de Abril</td>
        <td>Domingo de resurección</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g5" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Lunes 1 de Mayo</td>
        <td>Día del trabajo</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g6" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Sábado 16 de Septiembre</td>
        <td>Día de la independencia</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g7" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Lunes 20 de Noviembre</td>
        <td>Revolución Mexicana</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" id="g8" min="1" max="8" required class="num"></td>
        <td>Domingo 25 de Diciembre</td>
        <td>Navidad</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Guardar" id ="btn_guardia" class="btn btn-info btn-block">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```